# Python KIVY: TextInput does not let me write inside of it

Tags: python, kivy

I'm making an app that needs a text input (the aim is to create a graphical shell but no matter). When I try to write anything in the text input, nothing happens and I can't write inside of it.
Here is my code. If you want to test it to see the text input, you have to launch the app and then you click on one of the ">" green buttons on the right, then you click on "python 3 shell".

.py:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock

from functools import partial

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_width', 400)
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_height', 300)
Config.write()


class SM(ScreenManager):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SM, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Main(Screen):

    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)
    view = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)

    def create_scrollview(self, dt):
        base = ["connection {}".format(i) for i in range(40)]
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2, padding=10, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter("height"))

        for element in base:
            layout.add_widget(Button(text=element, size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None),
                                     background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1)))

            right_btn = Button(text=">", id=element, size=(50,50), size_hint=(None, None), background_color=(0, 1, 0, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            right_btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.open_connected, right_btn))
            layout.add_widget(right_btn)

        scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(1, None), size=(Window.width, Window.height))
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)
        self.ids.view.add_widget(scrollview)

    def open_connected(self, fun, name):
        self.manager.get_screen('connection_screen').ids.title.text = name.id
        self.manager.current = "connection_screen"

class Connection(Screen):

    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Connection, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Py3Shell(Screen):

    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Py3Shell, self).__init__(**kwargs)


Builder.load_file("gui.kv")

class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        return SM()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

.kv:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<SM>:

    Main:
        name: "main_screen"
        id: main_screen

    Connection:
        name: "connection_screen"
        id: connection_screen

    Py3Shell:
        name: "py3shell_screen"
        id: py3shell_screen

<Main>:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button:
            size: (8,8)
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            text: "|"
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            on_press: root.isShownMenu = not root.isShownMenu

        BoxLayout:
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 120 if root.isShownMenu else 0
            height: 120
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            opacity: 1 if root.isShownMenu else 0

            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"

        ScrollView:
            id:view

<Connection>:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button:
            size: (8,8)
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            text: "|"
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            on_press: root.isShownMenu = not root.isShownMenu

        BoxLayout:
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 120 if root.isShownMenu else 0
            height: 120
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            opacity: 1 if root.isShownMenu else 0

            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'

            GridLayout:
                cols: 2
                size: (50, 50)
                size_hint: (1, None)

                Button:
                    size: (50, 50)
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    text: "<"
                    on_press: root.manager.current = "main_screen"

                Button:
                    id: title
                    size: (50, 50)
                    size_hint: (1, None)
                    background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    text: ""


            BoxLayout:

                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'left'
                    anchor_y: 'top'

                    Button:
                        size: (80, 80)
                        size_hint: (1, None)
                        text: "Python 3 shell"
                        on_press: root.manager.current = "py3shell_screen"

                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'right'
                    anchor_y: 'top'

                    Button:
                        size: (80, 80)
                        size_hint: (1, None)
                        text: "System shell"


<Py3Shell>:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button:
            text: "<"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)

        Button:
            text: "Python 3 shell"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (1, None)

        Button:
            text: "X"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)

    BoxLayout:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: (50, 50)
        size_hint: (1, None)

        Label:
            text: "prompt $>"
            size: (75, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)

        TextInput: # <----------------------------------------- here
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (1, None)
            background_color: (.1, .1, .1, 1)
            color: (1, 1, 1, 1)

        Button:
            text: ">"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I ran your code I got warnings about multiple screens with the same name. I believe that was because you were running `Builder.load_file("gui.kv")` and ignoring the returned `Main` Screen. So I rewrote your gui.kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.0


<Main>:
    name: "main_screen"
    id: main_screen

    GridLayout:
        id: glayout
        cols: 3

        Button:
            size: (8,8)
            size_hint_x: None
            text: "|"
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            on_press: main_screen.isShownMenu = not main_screen.isShownMenu

        BoxLayout:
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 120 if main_screen.isShownMenu else 0
            height: 120
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            opacity: 1 if main_screen.isShownMenu else 0

            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"

        ScrollView:
            id: view
            size_hint: 1, 1

<Connection>:
    name: "connection_screen"
    id: connection_screen

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button:
            size: (8,8)
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            text: "|"
            background_color: (0,1,0,1)
            on_press: connection_screen.isShownMenu = not connection_screen.isShownMenu

        BoxLayout:
            id: menu
            orientation: 'vertical'
            width: 120 if connection_screen.isShownMenu else 0
            height: 120
            size_hint: (None, 1)
            opacity: 1 if connection_screen.isShownMenu else 0

            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"
            Button:
                text: "Menu button"

        BoxLayout:
            id: blayout
            orientation: 'vertical'

            GridLayout:
                id: conlayout
                cols: 2
                size: (50, 50)
                size_hint: (1, None)

                Button:
                    size: (50, 50)
                    size_hint: (None, None)
                    text: "<"
                    on_press: connection_screen.manager.current = "main_screen"

                Button:
                    id: title
                    size: (50, 50)
                    size_hint: (1, None)
                    background_color: (0, 0, 1, 1)
                    color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
                    text: ""


            BoxLayout:

                spacing: 10
                padding: 10

                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'left'
                    anchor_y: 'top'

                    Button:
                        size: (80, 80)
                        size_hint: (1, None)
                        text: "Python 3 shell"
                        on_press: connection_screen.manager.current = "py3shell_screen"

                AnchorLayout:
                    anchor_x: 'right'
                    anchor_y: 'top'

                    Button:
                        size: (80, 80)
                        size_hint: (1, None)
                        text: "System shell"


<Py3Shell>:
    name: "py3shell_screen"
    id: py3shell_screen

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3

        Button:
            text: "<"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)

        Button:
            text: "Python 3 shell"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (1, None)

        Button:
            text: "X"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)

    BoxLayout:

    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        size: (50, 50)
        size_hint: (1, None)

        Label:
            text: "prompt $>"
            size: (75, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)

        TextInput: # <----------------------------------------- here
            id: ti
            height: 50
            size_hint: (1, None)
            background_color: (1, 1, 1, 1)
            color: (1, 1, 1, 1)

        Button:
            text: ">"
            size: (50, 50)
            size_hint: (None, None)
            background_color: (0, 1, 0, 1)
```

I still had the non-editable TextInput, so I added the `on_enter()` method to set focus to the TextInput widget. And the SM class is no longer needed. Here is the modified .py file:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.10.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.clock import Clock

from functools import partial

from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_width', 400)
Config.set('graphics', 'minimum_height', 300)
Config.write()


class Main(Screen):

    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)
    view = ObjectProperty(None)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.create_scrollview)

    def create_scrollview(self, dt):
        base = ["connection {}".format(i) for i in range(40)]
        layout = GridLayout(cols=2, padding=10, spacing=10, size_hint_y=None)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter("height"))

        for element in base:
            layout.add_widget(Button(text=element, size=(50, 50), size_hint=(1, None),
                                     background_color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1)))

            right_btn = Button(text=">", id=element, size=(50,50), size_hint=(None, None), background_color=(0, 1, 0, 1), color=(1, 1, 1, 1))
            right_btn.bind(on_press=partial(self.open_connected, right_btn))
            layout.add_widget(right_btn)

        scrollview = self.ids['view']
        scrollview.add_widget(layout)

    def open_connected(self, fun, name):
        self.manager.get_screen('connection_screen').ids.title.text = name.id
        self.manager.current = "connection_screen"


class Connection(Screen):

    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Connection, self).__init__(**kwargs)

class Py3Shell(Screen):

    isShownMenu = BooleanProperty(True)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Py3Shell, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        super().on_enter(*args)
        self.ids.ti.focus = True


class GUI(App):

    def build(self):
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Main())
        sm.add_widget(Connection())
        sm.add_widget(Py3Shell())
        return sm

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GUI().run()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped a lot !